# How do I level up stats instead of skills in DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2

I've seen a few guides for various heroes (mainly on DotA Fire) that advise leveling stats instead of skills at level 15, then from 17 to 25 (when skills have been maxed). How do I do this? (What do I need to  do after clicking on the gold 'level up' button?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you level up, a gold "Level Up" button will appear right above your character's portrait.
Upon clicking it, a gold/yellow border will circle your stats bar and any abilities you are able to upgrade.

To level up your stats instead of skills, click the stats box and 2 extra points (per time you level up your stats instead of abilities) will be allocated to each attribute. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> when the gold button flashes (instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> which is the hotkey to level up your skills).

As a sidenote, leveling stats is really good and often overlooked in the "guides" that you can use in-game. Stats is especially good when learning the game, so you can focus on the action with higher damage when it happens and not your 6 different <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> hotkeys/abilities/item abilities.

Comment: @aytimothy, That edit is more than the answer itself... but +1 now.

Comment: @kim123, the rep doesn't go to me. | Btw, you can use <html tags> in the editor... But only markup in the comments.

Comment: @aytimothy despite the good will it's better to let the answerer edit his post himself. If you have this much information to add, better create your own answer or comment and suggest this edit.

Comment: @WizardLizard should I revert the changes?

Comment: @aytimothy nah its ok don't worry. Just keep it in mind for future edits ;)

Comment: Am I able to bind the `U` to something else? I set the attribute key in the options menu but for some reason I cannot use it in combination with ctrl

Comment: Amazing edit @aytimothy, I'm too fast when I type. Thanks! @Wandang there should be a hotkey called "Upgrade stats" that you can bind to whatever you like. If you change the `u`, then you also need to change that particular one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't click anything. Just press Ctrl+U when you see that you've got a new level.

Read more about "Attribute Bonus" here http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Attributes?cookieSetup=true